# Enable 32-bit Applications On SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, iis

I have one sharepoint application is running.
Now, I want to run this application in 32bit mode for some backward compatibility

I have Window Server2008 with IIS 7 with MOSS 2007 running.
I have changed application pool advance setting and enabled Enable 32-bit Applications

After enabling this SharePoint Site working previously stop working and Saying Internal Server Error - 500

I have seen the Eventviewer and nothing there.

If I revert back to Enable 32-bit Applications to false then all working ok.

Can anyone tell me what's happning here?

Comment: Just a comment here, MOSS has two types of installs, 32bit and 64bit. Which one did you install?

Comment: My client has installed this, so, I am not sure How can I know which  
Installation is done?

Answer (score 1):

You must install the 32bit version of MOSS if you need to run MOSS in 32bit mode on a 64bit platform.
To determine of the current installation is 32 or 64bit, take a look in which Program Files folder it's installed into.
64bit -> \Program Files
32bit -> \Program Files (x86)

Comment: I have 
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\12.0
Where Bin, Config, Data, Log etc.. Folder are there

But My Database files I can find here
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office Servers\12.0\Data\MSSQL.4\MSSQL\Data

Comment: It seems that you are running 64bit, and you must install the 32bit instead if you must run 32bit. It also seems that you are running the 32bit SQL Server edition (which isn't really related to the MOSS platform version)

Comment: @Magnus Johansson, it's stated by Microsoft that it is "best" to have 64bits everywhere in your farm, including SQL server.

Comment: @naivists. Of course. But the original poster has the need to run 32bit MOSS. In situations where you have a dependency on 3rd party assemblies or components that are (for whatever(stupid) reason) compiled for 32bit only, one haven't got much choice.